# Is there any way to represent any function on a z=0 plane transform into an arbitrary differentiable continuous non-linear surface?

Tags: metric-spaces, 3d, mobius-transformation, nonlinear-analysis, geometric-transformation

#### Question

Let's assume that there is a given line or a given arbitrary function defined on a $z=0$ plane. For example, $x^2+y^2=1$ Now I twist the plane into a non-linear 3D surface that can be represented by any given continuous and differentiable equations, i.e. $f(x, y, z)=C$. For example, $ln(x^2+1)-xy+y^2+sinh(z)+xyz=12$ . (Well I don't know whether this is my valid function, but you know what I am meaning). How could I represent this line or function in analytical equations including the reversible form now? (e.g. if it could be like linear algebra to be reversible, the solution could be reused for later calculation)

You could think this like *"a straight line on a waving flag"*.

#### My current idea

1. Transformation of the space coordinate system maybe a good and effective solution to this. However, nearly all transformations are simple and linear. The non-linear transformation are only limited to the specified surfaces.
2. Linear algebra (matrix) might not be the solution as it only changes the coefficients of x, y and z. Seems not to be used for non-linear transformation.
3. Projection is **not** the solution. As the shape of the surface may over bend, the projected area will cover the wanted details.
4. I have asked for someone else for suggestions. One of them said complex coordinate may be the solution. Is this a good idea or impossible or the overkill to this question?
5. I found Mobius Transformation in complex system but it involves spherical projection. As said in Point 2, this might not really feasible.

Much appreciated if you have any idea or suggested publications.

### ------ EDIT 11 JUNE 2020 ------

According to @Lubin thought, I use Mathematica to Plot a simple example as shown in Figure.
[image: Parametric translation of a circle]

The plane only rotates at a certain angle as $X=x$, $Y=y$, and $Z=x+y$. The circle is stretched, not as expected that the circle is only rotated someway. It seems that this might not the final solution to this question.

Comment: Actually, what I want to achieve is to get the area bounded by several boundary functions on the twisted surface. But the key is to get the expressions of boundary functions. Therefore, I ask my question as this.

Comment: Just an update to this question. I have done the related research. The discussion result from this question is too complex to be solved. The scope was reduced and the question is much simplified. Please see [**this link**](http://dx.doi.org/10.13140/RG.2.2.15843.07206) from my thesis put on the ResearchGate. The result from this question is put in the appendix of the thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think you want to set up your statement of what’s being looked for in that way. For one thing, just giving an equation in $\Bbb R^3$ does not guarantee that the surface so defined will be anything like the  plane or any part of it. For instance, one might write down an equation defining a two-holed closed surface in $3$-space, which could not be wrapped over by the whole plane.

Much easier, and much more a description of your “twisting” of the plane, would be to describe the target surface parametrically:
$$
\begin{align}
X&=\xi(x,y)\\
Y&=\eta(x,y)\\
Z&=\zeta(x,y)\,,
\end{align}
$$
where I’m using only two variables $x,y$ ’cause you’re starting on the $z=0$ plane.

Then, if you’ve been foresighted enough to describe your curve in the plane not by a single equation in $x$ and $y$, but parametrically $x=f(t), y=g(t)$, you’ll be golden, ’cause your new curve is simply
$$
\begin{align}
X&=\xi\bigl(f(t),g(t)\bigr)\\
Y&=\eta\bigl(f(t),g(t)\bigr)\\
Z&=\zeta\bigl(f(t),g(t)\bigr)\,,
\end{align}
$$
and that will put you in a much more favorable position.

Comment: This is the most ideal case. However, sometimes the surface can only be described by a single equation, which I could approximate it with another equation with the whole defined range and transform it into the parametric equations. And now the question will become "How to transform any single equation into parametric equations". Thanks. Accepted

Comment: What you say is quite right; but your idea of “twisting” suggested to me a continuous path  from the untwisted $z$ plane to the twisted surface, whatever it was, and that’s just what’s called a homotopy, and necessarily giving you a parametrized surface. Anyhow…

Comment: The homotopy function seems to have another element involved, which is time. I do not find that parametric equations are the necessary requirements on the definition on Wikipedia. It seems that homotopy focuses on the process of change, and both initial and final functions are the conditions to that. However, this may be quite helpful for my later research. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I use Mathematica to do a simple example. The result will deform itself even if it is only a rotation. This solution might not be what I expect although this is an intuitive solution at first. Please see the picture in my last question edit for the example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is not completed. One additional thing to consider: then the length will never change. So I just need to see the length then I can get the equation with the roughly shaped one with your method!

Comment: I like this last comment. Except for one thing: wouldn’t preservation of distances along the original surface restrict you to surfaces that you can get with the moves of origami? You can’t deform a plane into a hemisphere if you’re preserving distances within the original plane, after all.

Comment: I represent the planar pattern with polar coordinates to keep the distances from the origin the same. Additionally, the surface is kind of restricted: only one curvature is allowed for any single point on the surface <- Just imagine to bend a piece of paper without deformation and folding in reality. Therefore, the hemisphere is out of scope. I may need to make the question clearer.